# How to get data from webhook with content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8?

Tags: php, api, webhooks

I have setup a webhook in zoho crm but when ever i try to fetch the data with `json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true)` it is always blank. From the look of the content-type the data is not json, i ahve tried everything and i still can't get the data from the webhook.

Any help is much appreciated.

Capture of HTTP POST Request:
[image]

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init', 'register_api_hooks' );

function register_api_hooks() {
    register_rest_route( 'ep-to-zoho-crm/v1', '/updatecompany', array(
        'methods'  => 'POST',
        'callback' => 'webhook_listener',
    ));
};

function webhook_listener($request){
    // We don't want to process if it did not come from webhook
    //if( !isset( $_GET['companyid'] ) ) { return; }

    //$data = $request->get_param( 'companyid' );

    if ( isset( $_REQUEST['companyid'] ) ) {
        file_put_contents(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'crm.txt', 'works');
    }else{
        file_put_contents(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'invalid.txt', 'invalid');
    } 

    /*$data = $_POST['companyid'];

    file_put_contents(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'crm.txt', $data);


    $json_string = json_encode($_POST);

    $save = file_put_contents(plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ).'crm.json', $json_string);*/
}
add_action( 'init', 'webhook_listener' );
```

and then my webhook url looks like this https://example.com/wp-json/ep-to-zoho-crm/v1/updatecompany

Comment: if the data isn't JSON but it is a normal form-urlencoded submission then generally it will be available in the $_POST or $_GET array (depending on the HTTP method used). This is the standard way PHP receives data from HTML forms, for instance. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php - it's documented as "An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request."

Comment: I have tried $_POST but i still don't get any data, when i send the data to a requestbin i can see the data but when i send it to my own url it's blank.

Comment: Can you show us what the HTTP request itself looks like please.

Comment: @ADyson i updated my post with an image, please have a look.

Comment: And this request is normally being sent to your PHP script? In that case `$_POST["companyid"]` should contain the value shown in the screenshot (for `companyid=334592...etc`)

Comment: @ADyson i have updated my post with more code, please let me now if i am doing it correctly. This code was placed in a php file inside a custom plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was my server was not configured correctly and so the data was being blocked when sent to my webhook url.